# Convert Caffemodel Into Tensorflow.js Model

Tags: python, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have a caffemodel which is supposed to return cropped faces from an image (`face_detector.prototxt` and `face_detector.caffemodel`). This is being used in python code with TensorFlow, but I don't think I can directly load caffemodel in react native, so I thought if I can convert it into a TensorFlow.js model I could use it in react native with [TensorFlow.js For React Native](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-react-native). Is there any way I can do that? Or maybe a way to load it directly into react native?

This is how it's loaded in Python:

```
import os
import cv2

def load_face_detector_model():
    print("[INFO] loading face detector model...")
    prototxtPath = os.path.sep.join(["face_detector", "face_detector.prototxt"])
    weightsPath = os.path.sep.join(["face_detector", "face_detector.caffemodel"])
    net = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)
    return net
```

Comment: what does `print(type(net))` and `print(type(dir(a)))` give you? Maybe there's a `.save` method somewhere.

Comment: I'm not able to run that code atm but according to [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#ga3b34fe7a29494a6a4295c169a7d32422), readNet method returns a [Net Object](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d30/classcv_1_1dnn_1_1Net.html)